# A four dimensional mapping Torus Parallelizable?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles, compact-manifolds

I want to show that under certain conditions a four dimensional mapping torus is parallelizable.
Let $X$ be a 3 dimensional, compact, orientable Riemann manifold. We know that every such manifold is parallelizable. That means we have three vector fields $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}$ such that they form a basis at any point. Let $f: X \to X $ be a diffeomorphism such that ($f_{p})_{*}X_{i}(p)=X_{i}(f(p))$. Now can I conclude that the mapping torus $M_f$ is parallelizable?

Comment: Yes, of course, just think about the suspension foliation of the mapping torus.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks a lot for your comment. However here I still need the condition on the diffeomorphism right?

Comment: Yes, you need a condition, but maybe not as strong as the one you wrote.